# How to sum values within same time steps range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops

I wanted the sum of values for some ids, given timestamps are on same day, but I need the sum to be synchronized "near" around a fixed time step, so here is an example for 5 minutes "snap to grid" time.

```
id   datecol            value
------------------------------
A   2020-03-01 13:03    10 |
B   2020-03-01 13:02    20 |   <---- within range of 13:00
C   2020-03-01 13:01    15 |

A   2020-03-01 13:07    50 |
B   2020-03-01 13:05    50 |    <---- within range of 13:05  
C   2020-03-01 13:06    40 |
     ...
```

Result

```
id        datecol         value
------------------------------
ABC    2020-03-01 13:00    45
ABC    2020-03-01 13:05    140
    ...
```

Here is how I did it :

```
...
SET @HOUR='13:05'; SELECT 'ABC',CONCAT(date(datecol),' ',@HOUR), sum(value) as value from 
tbl where (id="A" or id="B" or id="C") and 
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time(datecol),@HOUR))>-2.5*60 and 
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time(datecol),@HOUR))<=2.5*60 
group by date(datecol) 
...
```

And so on for 24 hs..

So it's a loop of 12 * 24 = 288 selects !

Is there any **less insane** way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Code to create the table and insert:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `datecol` datetime NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `datecol`, `value`) VALUES
('A', '2020-03-01 13:00:00', 10),
('B', '2020-03-01 13:02:00', 20),
('C', '2020-03-01 13:01:00', 15),
('A', '2020-03-01 13:07:00', 50),
('B', '2020-03-01 13:05:00', 50),
('C', '2020-03-01 13:06:00', 40);
```

Comment: I imagine *every* other way would be less insane. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

With input

```
id  datecol               value
A   2020-03-01 13:03:00   10
B   2020-03-01 13:02:00   20
C   2020-03-01 13:01:00   15
A   2020-03-01 13:07:00   50
B   2020-03-01 13:05:00   50
C   2020-03-01 13:06:00   40
```

You could use `FROM_UNIXTIME` MySQL function and group by the result of this function to produce timeranges

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '') ids, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol) % (5 * 60)) timerange,
    SUM(value)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY timerange
order by timerange;
```

Output:

```
ids   timerange             total
ABC   2020-03-01 13:00:00   45
ABC   2020-03-01 13:05:00   140
```

Comment: Ok updated my asnwer using `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` functions